# How best to create this arrow shaped div/button?

Tags: html, css, sass

first post on Stack. I've been asked to recreate this design for a project and I'm not entirely sure how best to approach recreating this div/button with an arrowed bottom side.

[image: image of button with non-rectangular polygon shape]

I'm fairly comfortable with most CSS conventions but for custom styles like this, I'm a bit lost as to a starting point. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much,
Nathan

Comment: Hi! At this site, we require you to atleast try to solve the problem yourself first. As it is the question is too broad. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Comment: Hi - thanks for that - I wasn't necessarily looking for a solution, maybe more of a suggestion of some properties to look at/consider as I've done some extensive googling and can't really find anything that matches this ...

Comment: Look for CSS shapes, or maybe this [generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) you can use them with trick. maybe this [also](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.button
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(128,250,128);
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.button::after
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    content: "";
    width: 0px;
    border-color: rgb(128,250,128) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 30px 0px 30px; /*10 is the height and 30 is half of parent width*/
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  button
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CSS you need to make a `div/button` angled downwards:

```css
.menu {
  background-color: #0b0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
.menu.active {
background-color: #0d0;
}
.menu.active::after {
  border-top: 10px solid #0d0;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu.active::before {
  border-top: 10px solid #000;
  border-left: 75px solid transparent;
  border-right: 75px solid transparent;
  bottom: -11px;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  HOME
</div>
<div class="menu active">
  MORE REVIEWS
</div>
<div class="menu">
  ABOUT
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @Nathan